# Beacon development in adobe air

Tags: beacon, distriqt

I have bought three bluecats and three kontakt.io beacons and I'm wondering if i can use the com.distriqt.Beacon ANE for my application development ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [distriqt Beacon ANE](https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Beacon) supports any beacon adhering to Apple's iBeacon standard.

Both bluecats and kontakt beacons can be formatted to the iBeacon standard so you should be able to use them with this ANE.